# Roulette Wheel - Counting Even/Odd Streak w/o an Array

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm having a bit of trouble with a part of my code. We're supposed to have a random generator inside a loop that generates 1,000,000 random numbers. Afterwards, we have to have a counter that counts the longest streak of evens and odds, and compare it to 1/37 * (n-1) (# of expected repeats) and (1/37)^2 * (n-1) (# of expected threepeats). We haven't learned arrays, so he expects us to complete the assignment without arrays. It seems to be generating streaks correctly, however, my numbers are consistently high when you look closer (ex. I generate a streak of 29 when the expected streak per formula is 19). If the generator is truly random, it should be closer to the expected number. I've provided my code below:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        int randomNumber = gen.nextInt(37);
        wheel.setNumber(randomNumber);
        String numberColor = wheel.getColor();

//COUNTS THE LONGEST STRING OF EVENS
        if ((lastNum % 2 == 0) && (randomNumber % 2 == 0) && randomNumber != 0 && lastNum != 0) {
            tempEven++;
            tempOdd = 1;
        } else { 
            if (tempEven > longestEven) {
                longestEven = tempEven;
                tempEven = 1;
            }
        }

//COUNTS THE LONGEST STRING OF ODDS
        if ((lastNum % 2 == 1) && (randomNumber % 2 == 1) && randomNumber != 0 && lastNum != 0) {
            tempOdd++;
            tempEven = 1;
        } else {
            if (tempOdd > longestOdd) {
                longestOdd = tempOdd;
                tempOdd = 1;
            }
        }
}
```

If someone could check my code and make sure my logic is correct, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: where is lastNum declared? and how is it being updated? Or is this what you need help on?

Comment: lastNum is initialized at the top (unseen here), beginning at 1. I'm not exactly sure where I'm going wrong with my logic.

Comment: See my answer, because it seems like you're not resetting the streak in all cases. For example, if it goes "even, even, even, odd, even" tempEven will end up being 4 after this iteration when it should have been reset to 1 from 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in how you use your `if` statements:

```
    if ((lastNum % 2 == 0) && (randomNumber % 2 == 0) && randomNumber != 0 && lastNum != 0) {
        tempEven++;
        tempOdd = 1;
    } else { 
        if (tempEven > longestEven) {
            longestEven = tempEven;
            tempEven = 1;
        }
    }
```

Here you are assuming that if the condition is `false`, it means that `randomNum` is odd, which is not the case (e.g. `lastNum` is odd and `randomNum` is even will return `false`). Same thing with your second `if` statement.

Something like this would work:

```
if(randomNum is even) {
    if(lastNum is even) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
} else {
    if(lastNum is even) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, it seems that you are only resetting tempEven to 1 in 2 cases only. These cases are

- tempEven is greater than longestEven (current streak of evens is
  longer than the longest streak of evens)
- two consecutive odd numbers are found

However, one case that is left out is when an odd number is found after an even number, breaking the current streak of evens. Your code does attempt to deal with this in the else part of both if statements. But if tempEven is not greater than longestEven, then tempEven never gets reset to 1. If the streak is broken, tempEven should be reset no matter what. In this case though, let's say we find an odd number after a streak of 8 even numbers in a row. If longestEven is 10, then tempEven won't be reset. And if the next number is an even number, then tempEven still won't be reset because longestEven is still greater. Then, let's say another even number is found, the original streak that should have been broken keeps being added to. As you can see, this could account for the inaccurate streak number. This same type of logic applies to the streak of odd numbers as well. My suggestion is to use if-else statements to deal with all 3 cases separately. With else if statements, only one of the statements in the sequence (each represents a separate case) will be executed, which really cleans up the code.

- two consecutive even numbers found (add to tempEven)
- one odd and one even number found next to each other (check to see if the streaks are greater than the longest ones found so far and update accordingly, then reset the temporary streaks back to 1)
- two consecutive odd numbers found (add to tempOdd)

  ```
  for(int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
      int randomNumber = gen.nextInt(37);
      wheel.setNumber(randomNumber);
      String numberColor = wheel.getColor();

  //COUNTS THE LONGEST STRING OF EVENS
      if ((lastNum % 2 == 0) && (randomNumber % 2 == 0) && randomNumber != 0 && lastNum != 0) {
           tempEven++;
      }
  //ONCE A STREAK IS BROKEN BY FINDING A ODD NUM AFTER A EVEN NUM
  //OR A EVEN NUM AFTER A ODD NUM
  //THIS ELSE IF STATEMENT COULD BE SEPARATED INTO TWO ELSE IF STATEMENTS
  //BUT IT IS MEANT TO ILLUSTRATE A CASE
      else if(((lastNum % 2 != 0 && randomNumber % 2 == 0) || (lastNum % 2 == 0 && randomNumber % 2 != 0)) && (randomNumber != 0 && lastNum != 0)){
           if(tempEven > longestEven){
                 longestEven = tempEven;
           }
           if(tempOdd > longestOdd){
                 longestOdd = tempOdd;
           }
           //streak should be reset no matter what once this case is found
           tempEven = 1;
           tempOdd = 1;

      }
  //COUNTS THE LONGEST STRING OF ODDS
      else if ((lastNum % 2 == 1) && (randomNumber % 2 == 1) && randomNumber != 0 && lastNum != 0) {
          tempOdd++;
          tempEven = 1;
      } 
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is way too much code. Try this:

```
int longestEvenRun = 0, longestOddRun = 0, evenRun = 0, oddRun = 0, last = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    int randomNumber = gen.nextInt(37);
    int odd = randomNumber & 1; // 1 if odd, 0 if even
    if (odd == last) {
        longestOddRun = Math.max(++oddRun, longestOddRun);
        evenRun = 0;
    } else {
        longestEvenRun = Math.max(++evenRun, longestEvenRun);
        oddRun = 0;
    }
    last = odd;
}
```

The only thing perhaps needing explanation here is `randomNumber & 1`, which does a bitwise AND of the random number with `1` to mask off all but the lowest order bit, which is `1` for off numbers and `0` for even numbers. Doing this greatly simplifies the logic. Note that the `last` variable is initialized with a value that is neither off nor even, so the first iteration will work correctly.